# How do make angularjs update the dom after I change the value of ng-show

Tags: dom, angularjs

I have the following the template

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div>
        <p><button ng-click="editItem()">Edit</button></p>
    </div>
        <div class="span10">
        <input type="text" value={{item.helpText}} ng-model="question.helpText" required>
        </div>
        <div id="done" ng-show={{item.state}}>
            <div>
                <p><button ng-click="doneEditItem()">Done</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

In my controller I have code that sets `item.state = false` initially,this hides the `done` div and consequently the "Done" button as expected at start up. In the `editItem()` function, I have code that sets the item.state=true, when the user clicks the "Edit" button.

I was expecting that when I set item.state = true, the `doneEditItem` button would become visible again. Currently this is not happening. Is there some angularjs function that I should call that will make the done button visible after setting `item.state=true`?

Comment: Try `ng-show="item.state"` -- no {{}}s.

Comment: I would add that `value={{item.helpText}} ng-model="question.helpText"` looks fishy to me... You should be setting up `question.helpText` in your controller and leaving the value attribute off - at least that's my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow), like many Angular directives, takes an [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).  This expression is evaluated against the current scope, so {{}}s are not required -- actually they can't be used where an Angular expression is required.  So use `ng-show="item.state"` rather than `ng-show={{item.state}}`.

{{}}s are used elsewhere in your HTML, when you want the Angular compiler to interpolate something.  E.g., `<p>Hello {{name}}</p>`.